# Whether a redo log is generated when the transaction is rollback

Tags: mysql, innodb

We know that when we execute an update statement, mysqld will modify the data page and write a redo log. When we execute the commit statement, redo log will be written to the file.
If we execute rollback instead of commit, mysqld will change the data page back to the previous state. At this time, will it be written to the redo log?

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: If the transaction is rolled back, is there any need to redo it in case of a failure?

Comment: No need for such -- a redo cannot be undone.  (Anyway, you would end up with an infinite loop.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think of a way to verify it. First, I find the redo log and record its size. Second, I start transaction and execute an update statement. wait a minute, I record the size of the redo log. Finally, I execute a rollback statement, and record the size of the redo log. Through these three steps, I think the answer can be obtained. 
I will try it when I have time